# Github "C/ C++ with Make" Workflow doesn't produce artifact

Tags: building-github-actions, github-actions-artifacts

I am trying to build a simple app using `make`. GitHub has a workflow template, "[C/C++ with make](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/b1df8a546ed4d0f27d46aaf2f8ac1118bc522638/ci/c-cpp.yml)" and I was able to format the build instructions from the repo without too much trouble. When I ran the action, it completed successfully, but it did not create any artifacts. I would expect that running `make` would produce an artifact file (I have forked other repos with existing app-building actions, and I was able to find the compiled .exe in the artifacts after running *those* actions. It's just this action that I wrote myself that I'm having trouble with.)

To be clear, when I reference "artifacts", I am referring to how after running a workflow, you can view its results at **github.com/{username}/{repoName}/actions/runs/{runNumber}**, where there are separate boxes (if applicable) for **annotations** and **artifacts**. You can click to download files from the artifacts box. I'm not concerned about pushing files to the repo.

The original build instructions are:

```bash
sudo apt install make gcc qtmultimedia5-dev libogg-dev libopus-dev libgl1-mesa-dev build-essential libssl-dev qtbase5-dev qtchooser qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev-tools gcc-multilib qttools5-dev-tools
find ./ -name '*.ts' -exec lrelease {} \;
qmake buildme.pro
make -j$(nproc)
```

And my `Build.yml` code is:

```yaml
name: Build

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: update outdated dependei
      run: sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
    - name: apt update
      run: sudo apt-get update
    - name: install dependencies
      run: sudo apt install -y --fix-missing make gcc qtmultimedia5-dev libogg-dev libopus-dev libgl1-mesa-dev build-essential libssl-dev qtbase5-dev qtchooser qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev-tools gcc-multilib qttools5-dev-tools
    - name: find file 
      run: find ./ -name '*.ts' -exec lrelease {} \;
    - name: qmake
      run: qmake buildme.pro
    - name: make
      run: make -j$(nproc)
```

And you can find [the logs for the `make` command on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/VN2p97Az)

I will admit I'm not familiar enough with make or qmake to know if I need to add further instructions in order to get an executable file as a result. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Your action does not upload any artifacts. You can use [actions/upload-artifact](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact) to do that:

```
    - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: program.exe
        path: "path/to/program.exe"
```

Comment: Did you read the question? The action doesn't *produce* any artifacts. While I am pretty new to Actions, I do know how to use `upload-artifact`, and it only works if there are artifacts in the first place. Right now, I'm doing this all pretty experimentally, so I don't need artifacts to be uploaded to the repo; I'm fine with downloading them manually. But again, the `make` command is not producing an artifact: THAT is the issue.

Comment: Your question has title "Workflow doesn't produce artifact", not "Make doesn't produce artifact". Your workflow does not produce any artifacts because it does not have actions for doing that. How do you know that `make` does not produce artifacts? Can you show `make` logs?

Comment: Sure, I will add the `make` logs. Perhaps I was presumptuous in thinking that people would read the question, not just the title. Feel free to edit the title if you have a better version in mind

Comment: I have read the full question and the edited one, and what I see is you complaining about workflow's artifacts (that's what appears on the github.com/{username}/{repoName}/actions/runs/{runNumber} pages), not make's artifacts (they are local files which are removed when workflow ends). So the title fits.

Comment: So in the provided `make`'s log there are no errors, seems like `buildme` has been generated. What makes you think that `make` does not produce artifacts?

Comment: I think it doesn't produce artifacts because after running the Action no artifacts have been produced... here's a screenshot, if that helps? https://postimg.cc/87sTsRH3

Comment: That would go back to the original question, then: "I will admit I'm not familiar enough with Make or Qmake to know if I need to add further instructions in order to get an executable file as a result. Am I missing something?" If `make` produced a file, then what do I need to do to make that file accessible as an Action Artifact?

Comment: You need to upload the generated file as an artifact of the workflow. That's exactly what upload-artifact does.

Comment: Ok, I'll try upload-artifact again and mess around with the parameters... I had included upload-artifact in a previous version of build.yml but removed it since it didn't seem to be doing anything. I suppose it's possible I had it misconfigured...... UPDATE: Well I got github to produce an artifact, but it just contains the same "buildme.pro" file. Not sure where the `make` command would save its output files in the Github Actions VM, so I'm just guessing around with the `path:` parameter

Comment: Upvoted the answer. Frankly, I have no idea on the matter. I felt that your patience in dealing with comments deserved a reward, @Doj

Comment: @ETL Unlike many other common languages, C++ does not have a standardized build system. Make is common, but not universal, and makefile configs vary wildly. Do not expect tight integrations for free like you might get for other languages.

Comment: @ETL you can run `find -type f` in order to print out all files in your pipeline. There you should find your build result.